# terraform conditional resource

Tags: terraform

I have the following and I want to know what I am doing wrong, as I am sure I shouldn't have to double my code just because of a condition.

So I want to do:

```
variable "https" { value = true }

resource "aws_security_group" "http_instance_sg" {
  count       = "${var.https ? 0 : 1}"

  ......

}
resource "aws_security_group" "https_instance_sg" {
  count       = "${var.https ? 1 : 0}"

  ......

}

resource "aws_elb" "fe_elb" {
  security_groups = ["${var.https ? aws_aws_security_group.https_instance_sg.id : aws_aws_security_group.http_instance_sg.id}"]
   .....
}
```

But when I do this terraform complains that `http_instance_sg` cant be found, which I get it hasn't be built, but surely I dont have to double up on all the code and have:

```
 resource "aws_elb" "http_fe_elb" {
    count = "${var.https ? 0 : 1}"
    security_groups = ["${aws_aws_security_group.http_instance_sg.id}"]
   .....
  }

 resource "aws_elb" "https_fe_elb" {
    count = "${var.https ? 1 : 0}"
    security_groups = ["${aws_aws_security_group.https_instance_sg.id}"]
   .....
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

The way you are currently defining the code with a count means that the response of the resource is a list. This means you will need to access the values differently

```
resource "aws_elb" "fe_elb" {
  security_groups = ["${var.https ? element(aws_security_group.https_instance_sg.*.id,0) : element(aws_security_group.http_instance_sg.*.id,0)}"]
   .....
}
```

It's worth noting that you will get an error if you try to access a list that is empty using this method.

This means you will need to [concat an empty value](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11210) to each to ensure the response of element doesn't throw.

**Example using concat**

`"${var.https ? element(concat(aws_security_group.https_instance_sg.*.id, list("")), 0) : element(concat(aws_security_group.http_instance_sg.*.id, list("")), 0)`

**Different approach**

Without seeing the code I might ask here if there is an easier way to achieve what you are trying to do using a [security_group_rule](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group_rule.html)

```
variable "https" { value = true }

resource "aws_security_group" "instance_sg" {
  # notice we no longer have a count here
}

resource "aws_elb" "fe_elb" {
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.instance_sg.id}"]
   .....
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "http" {
  count       = "${var.https ? 0 : 1}"
  .... http definitions
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.instance_sg.id}"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "https" {
  count       = "${var.https ? 0 : 1}"
  .... https definitions
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.instance_sg.id}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use :

```
resource "aws_security_group" "http_instance_sg"
```

instead of:

```
resource "aws_aws_security_group" "http_instance_sg"
```

there is no resource with name  "aws_aws_security_group" in Terraform , the error is most probably because of this resource name typo.

Hope it will help!

Comment: sorry thats just a typo in what I put in the question

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to add depends_on instruction ? Something like this (I'm not sure about the syntax) :

resource "aws_elb" "fe_elb" {
    depends_on  = [ aws_aws_security_group.https_instance_sg, aws_aws_security_group.http_instance_sg ]
  security_groups = ["${var.https ? aws_aws_security_group.https_instance_sg.id : aws_aws_security_group.http_instance_sg.id}"]
   .....
}