# Terraform: Route53, LB and CDN interdependency

Tags: dns, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

My team uses Terraform to deploy the necessary infrastructure.
Currently, our stack is composed of: AutoScalingGroup fronted by a Load-Balancer, and a Route53 DNS record that points to this LB;

We would like to extend the stack to include a Cloudfront distribution that points to the LB, and make the Route53 DNS record point to the CDN.

**I would like to** be able to:

- spin up Cloudfront and change the DNS record to point to the CDN, without causing any downtime;
- tear down the CDN, change the DNS to point to the load-balancer, without causing any downtime;

**The current configuration** is as follows:

```
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name                       = "${var.alb-name}"
  ...
}
```

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cdn" {
  count = "${var.use_cloudfront != "false" ? 1 : 0}"
  ...
}
```

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  count = "${var.domain-name != "" ? 1 : 0}"

  depends_on = ["aws_lb.alb", "aws_cloudfront_distribution.cdn"]  

  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id}"
  name    = "${var.domain-name}"
  type    = "A"

  alias = {
    // we use concat because 'count' makes the response of the resource a list. 
    // link to similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654774/terraform-conditional-resource
    name                   = "${var.use_cloudfront == "true" ? element(concat(aws_cloudfront_distribution.cdn.*.domain_name, list("")), 0) : aws_lb.alb.dns_name}"    
    zone_id                = "${var.use_cloudfront == "true" ? element(concat(aws_cloudfront_distribution.cdn.*.hosted_zone_id, list("")), 0) : aws_lb.alb.zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

**The current behavior** is as follows:

- the spin-up of the CDN, followed by re-routing the DNS record to point to the CDN, does not lead to any downtime;
- **the tear-down of the CDN, followed by re-routing the DNS record to the load-balancer, does cause downtime;**

I am aware that the `depends_on = ["aws_lb.alb", "aws_cloudfront_distribution.cdn"]` on the Route53 record might not be the best choice to create the desired behavior. However, I am not sure how to reach the desired behavior using terraform.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions to reach the desired behavior. Let me know if the provided information is insufficient. Thank you for your help, it is appreciated!

Comment: From a quick scan of things this should be the behaviour you see. What does the graph look like? Can you show the output from applying both of these changes if they don't do what you describe? Also you don't need the `depends_on` if you are using the outputs of those resources in that resource as Terraform already knows that it needs to build a dependency chain in that order.

Comment: I've created a gist with the output of the Terraform execution: https://gist.github.com/rafaelmarques7/03ec6e576faff81ef36d7fc878e85230
I do not have a graph to show you, I can do that in the following runs if necessary.
@ydaetskcoR

Comment: I believe that the problem during the CDN teardown, is that the Route53 will only change AFTER the CDN is destroyed. At this point, there is already down-time.
However, I don't know how to make it wait for the CDN when it is being created, and when NOT to wait for it when it is being destroyed. That is, during the teardown, ideally, we would like to re-route to the LB, without waiting for the CDN to be destroyed. That's why I believe the 'depends_on' is not the greatest strategy, but I don't know how to do what I need :s

Comment: Hmmm.. that looks odd to me. Can you edit the question to include the graphs for both plan and plan-destroy please?

Comment: I've managed to create the "plan" graph: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11wQ1EG0hvI__nIgpyTgqwP5CyL0YoHqa/view?usp=sharing
However, the command "terraform graph -type=plan-destroy | dot -
Tsvg > graph-destroy.svg" produced a blank svg file. I am not sure if the is wrong... @ydaetskcoR